# Newtonsoft Unexpected character while parsing value

Tags: c#, api, rest, json.net

I have the problem that I always get this error when deserializing an object. But when I use the bracketed code it works, but not when I retrieve it from my api

**Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.**

```
 public static async Task<string> GetData()
    {

      
        string data = await API.GetRequest("...");
        Trace.WriteLine(job_data);
        return data;
    }


 public Jobs()
    {


        //var JsonString = @"{'status':true,'data':[{'id':1,'user_id':1}]}";
      
        Trace.WriteLine(GetData().ToString());
        var JsonString = GetData().ToString();
        Model.Root DeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Root>(JsonString);
       
        Trace.WriteLine(DeserializedClass);  
        
        
        InitializeComponent();
        
        JobListBox.DataContext = DeserializedClass.Data;
        ContentControl.Content = DeserializedClass.Data;
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't do IO work in the constructor of a class.  It's always been a bad idea, but async/await makes it effectively impossible.  If you _really_ want to replicate similar functionality, make an async factory method (i.e. `public static async Task<Job> CreateJob()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetData Function is Async so you should await for it.

```
    var JsonString = GetData().ToString();
```

should be

```c#
        var JsonString = await GetData();
```

Comment: The problem is that the public Jobs() cannot be async 
`public partial class Jobs : Page
    {
      
        public  Jobs()
        {}}`

Comment: you can use one of two solutions :                                                                                    1- you also can use GetData().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); but be careful for the performance penalty of your form loading.                                                                              2- you can use the loaded event on your form and make the event handler [async void] and do your async work